# GCP integration with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, error-handling, terraform, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run terraform commands to create VM in my GCP account.

the code :

```
provider "google" {
project     = "My First Project"
region      = "us-east1"
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
name         = "terraform-instance"
machine_type = "f1-micro"
zone      = "us-east1-c"

boot_disk {
initialize_params {
  image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
}
}

network_interface {
# A default network is created for all GCP projects
network       = "default"
access_config {
   }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Error loading zone 'us-east1-c': googleapi: Error 403: Permission denied on resource project My First Project., forbidden
```

which role I need to add ?
where to add it ? to my GCP account or to service account ?

docs I find :
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#insufficient_permissions

(but I didn't find the answer there..)

thanks!

Comment: This can be easily found by googling a little more https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage

Answer (score 2):

The line **project = "My First Project"** is using the **Project Name**. Replace that with the **Project ID**.

Internally Google uses the **Project ID** or **Project Number** to uniquely identity projects. The Project Name is a descriptive name for your use. Multiple projects can have the same Project Name.

Comment: Bingo! thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the attached link?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance

There seems to be a lot of Project Id and missing information.
After confirmation, try running Terraform Command again.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your project id in the provider block.

```
provider "google" {
project     = "$PROJECT_ID"
region      = "us-east1"
}
```

You can check the project id using the console.

[project-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rIVr.png)